# Can not sort out how the Array is updated

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Hi i have this code of work from some one, its working fine as intended and i come to the point that this particular code is updating the value of temp[][]. but i can not figure our exaxtly where the temp[i][j]=updated is working out.
as the method is not returning any thing, and there is no assigning to temp[][]. all i see is the update_table[][]=temp;

when i try to print the temp before the loop and after the loop there is change in the array.

```
void var_init(String to_match_x,String to_match_y, String to_replace_x, String to_replace_y,String[][] temp)
{
    String t_match_x=to_match_x;
    String t_replace_x=to_replace_x;
    String t_match_y=to_match_y;
    String t_replace_y=to_replace_y;
    //String str=string;
    //add function to count variables find duplicates and assign values to them
    line();
    System.out.println("text to match:"+t_match_x);
    System.out.println("text to replace with:"+t_replace_x);
    System.out.println("text to match:"+t_match_y);
    System.out.println("text to replace with:"+t_replace_y);

    String[][] table_update=temp;
    line();

    System.out.println("starting fetching rules for updating variable");
    line();

    for(int i=0;i<table_update.length;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<table_update[0].length;j++)
            {
                 String replace_text=table_update[i][j];
                 System.out.println(replace_text);
                 String new_str;
                 new_str=replace_text.replaceAll("\\"+t_match_y,t_replace_y);         
                 new_str=new_str.replaceAll("\\"+t_match_x,t_replace_x);
                 table_update[i][j]=new_str;
                 System.out.println(table_update[i][j]);
                 line();

            }
}
```

Comment: The loop is updating the array.  Do you expect it to _not_ affect the array?

Comment: the loop is updating the table_update array but this changes are reflected in the temp array, when i put temp[][] before and after the loop as a println, it gives me the changed values.

Comment: This is because `table_update` refers to the same actual data as `temp`.  This is normal.

Comment: the line 

    String[][] tables_update= temp 
is assiging the temp array to table_update while the loop is changing the table_update and there is no connection after that with the temp so i am wondering where is the temp=table_update happening?

Comment: The prameter temp[][] in your method body is only an reference and it is assigned to the variable table_update therefore they are equivalent objects for the jvm.

Comment: @ZeusNet: not really 'equivalent', but rather 'the same' :-)

Comment: When you say `table_update[i][j] = value`, you can think in C/C++ terms, namely going to location in memory where `temp` is and assigning that cell to a value.

Comment: @Ijgw You are right :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are reffering to an array called `temp`

```
String[][] table_update=temp;
```

once you update `table_update` array `temp` will also be updated.if you dont want that to happen make a clone of `temp` array like this

```
String[][] table_update = temp.clone();
```

Comment: Great, mean both were referring to the same array and change in any one will be reflected in other one. nice and clear answer

Answer (score 0):

```
  String[][] table_update=temp;
```

This means that table_update and temp both have the same reference, so actually they are both the same array if one of them is updated its expected to the other one to be updated also.
You can create a new array (temp) and clone table_update to it that would solve your issue.